# Spring. Разница между аннотацией над интерфейсом и реализацией

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot

Не могу понять в чём разница между аннотацией над интерфейсом и реализацией.
Я много искал информации она не полная и мне кажется она не  верная. Решил разобраться в вопросе.

Рассмотрим

**1 Вариант**

Интерфейс

```java
    @Service
    public interface AuthenticationService {
    
        boolean authenticate(String username, String password);
    }
```

Реализация

```java
    public class InMemoryAuthenticationService implements AuthenticationService {
    
        @Override
        public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
            //...
        }
    }
```

И далее

```
 @Autowired
 private AuthenticationService authService;
```

Во многих источниках, в том числе и *stackoverflow* говорится, что при таком подходе есть 2 ключевые проблемы

1. Мы создаём лишнюю связь с *внешней библиотекой* (какой библиотекой???)
2. Мы можем столкнуться с **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException** (но почему-то нигде не говориться о аннотациях @Qualifier или @Primary и прочих способах)

**2 Вариант**

Интерфейс

```java
    public interface AuthenticationService {
    
        boolean authenticate(String username, String password);
    }
```

Реализация

```java
    @Service
    public class InMemoryAuthenticationService implements AuthenticationService {
    
        @Override
        public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
            //...
        }
    }
```

И далее

```
 @Autowired
 private InMemoryAuthenticationService authService;
```

В моей практике я всегда создавал интерфейс для сервиса и инжектил интерфейс.
Но сейчас стал иногда наблюдать и второй вариант.

**Вопросы**

Можете более подробно описать плюсы и минусы обоих вариантов?
Имеет ли смысл вообще тогда использовать интерфейсы, если у них всего 1 имплементация?

Comment: Я видел эту ссылку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351780/where-should-service-annotation-be-kept-interface-or-implementation 
но ответа там не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в многом.

Ты хочешь создать свой собственный класс от интерфейса. Зачем в самом интерфейсе ставить Spring-аннотацию, тем самым запрещая создавать класс от этого интерфейса не помещая его в контекст Spring? А если я не хочу, чтобы данный класс был бином?

Проблема в том, что разработчик должен сам решать, что будет делать данный класс.

Могу привести пример с обработкой исключений.

Вы разрабатываете библиотеку и в коде у вас есть место, которое может выбросить RuntimeException. Вопрос: нужно его обрабатывать или пробрасывать дальше? Ответ: пробрасывать дальше.

Если вы обработаете данное исключение в своей библиотеке, то потом, когда другой разработчик будет писать логику пользуясь вашей библиотекой он уже не сможет определить своё собственное поведение для возникшей ситуации, потому что ВЫ его уже определили и запретили как-то менять. Думаю, объяснил доступно.

Правильно делать вот так:

**Интерфейс**

```
public interface AuthenticationService {

    boolean authenticate(String username, String password);

}
```

**Реализация**

```
@Service
public class InMemoryAuthenticationService implements AuthenticationService {

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        //...
    }

}
```

**Использование**

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationService authService;
```

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос, имеет ли смысл создавать интерфейс для сервисов, у которых планируется 1 реализация?

Comment: Да, это в любом случае следование принципам SOLID. Точнее смысла нет никакого, Спрингу без разницы что внедрять. Это просто хорошая практика и так нужно делать даже тогда, когда это не несёт смысла, чтобы привыкать к такому написанию.

Comment: Разве это не странно. Сейчас в моём рабочем проекте около 200 сервисов и для каждого есть интерфейс. Но реализация всегда 1. Разве этот мусорный код не засоряет работу? Наверняка это отрицательно сказывается на производительности?